# Cooking with a crock pot - temp

Tags: temperature, slow-cooking, crockpot

I'm thinking about getting a slow cooker, so I was checking out some recipes.  Many say something along the lines of:

```
Cook Time
4 - 5 hours on LOW
2 - 2.5 hours on HIGH
Slow Cooker
4 - 4.5 Quarts
6 - 6.5 Quarts
```

Two questions:

1. Is it better to cook it on low or high? Obviously the time will be different, but will it usually taste better when done on low?
2. What is the stuff under `Slow Cooker` referring to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cooking "Low and Slow" allows the heat to break down the connective tissues that cause toughness in meat, creating a more tender dish.

As for what the "Slow Cooker" is referring to, that is the volume of the crock pot.

Answer (score 0):

For a pretty exhaustive list of why you would want to cook at a lower heat when time allows, [see this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/why-do-some-foods-taste-better-the-next-day/8392#8392) as most of the mechanics of letting your dish sit overnight apply when extending the cooking time by a few hours and lowering the temp.

In particular, I would look at [this answer regarding passive transport](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/8392/15); the difference being that you would be adding heat, further facilitating the listed mechanics