# Maximum cooking time for beef joint in slow cooker?

Tags: beef, cooking-time, slow-cooking, stews

I usually cook a joints of beef by browing it in a pan and then putting it in the slow cooker all day (about 8 hours) completely submerged in stock.

At the weekend I have family coming over, so the joint I have got is twice the size of the usual, and we are eating a couple of hours earlier than usual.

As I do not really fancy getting up in the early hours of the morning to put the beef on, I am thinking about putting it on last thing at night. This would be a cooking time of around 15 hours.

Is that too much? Is there a maximum time that beef joints (or any meat, for that matter) can be cooked in the slow cooker?

Would I be better to cook it the day before and then reheat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think there is a maximum to the duration of stewing a cut of beef. There is in my opinion such a thing as *too* tender and soft. If you plan to cook the meat as one large chunk you will have to add a little to your normal stewing time, but I would not go as high as 15 hours.

Cooking and re-heating is quite an interesting option though, as quite a few dishes benefit from this in terms of flavour. Perhaps a [general question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/why-do-some-foods-taste-better-the-next-day) on this subject, or a [more directly relevant one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54974/getting-seasoning-into-a-roast/54980#54980) would be of interest to you.

For me, the smaller the size of your chunks of meat, the more you should stick to your normal stewing time of 8 hours and the more you could consider making it a day early to enhance the taste.